# After converting json to yaml "null" field is added to all my values field

Tags: python, json, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

Bellow is Dictionary which i am using to convert in to json.

```
    string = {resources:{name:vm-created-by-deployment-manager,type:compute.v1.instance,properties : 
           {zone:us- 
         central1-a,machinetype:zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1,disk: 
         {deviceName:boot,type:PERSISTENT,boot:true ,autoDelete:true ,initializeParams: 
         {sourceImage:projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9}},networkInterfaces: 
         {network:global/networks/default}}}}
```

Here I am trying to convert dict data to json

```
    r = json.dumps(string)
    loaded_r = json.loads(r)
```

Here I am trying to convert json data ymal and writing to yaml file.

```
with open("C:\\Users\\Jeevitha\\Desktop\\DM_test.yaml", 'w') as f:
      yaml.dump(yaml.load(loaded_r,yaml.FullLoader), f,default_flow_style=False,sort_keys=False)
```

output what i got.

```
    resources:
      name:vm-created-by-deployment-manager: null
  type:compute.v1.instance: null
  properties:
     zone:us-central1-a: null
     machinetype:zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1: null
     disk:
       deviceName:boot: null
       type:PERSISTENT: null
       boot:true: null
       autoDelete:true: null
       initializeParams:
           sourceImage:projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9: null
     networkInterfaces:
        network:global/networks/default: null
```

output what i need.

```
      resources:
         name: vm-created-by-deployment-manager
         type: compute.v1.instance
         properties:
             zone: us-central1-a
             machineType: zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
             disks:
                deviceName: boot
                type: PERSISTENT
                boot: true
                autoDelete: true
                initializeParams:
                    sourceImage: projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9
             networkInterfaces:
                 network: global/networks/default
```

Comment: That's not a valid python dictionary in the beginning of your question.Can you update it to show the data structure you're actually working with? We should be able to paste it into a Python interpreter without error.

Comment: If I'm reading the code correctly, the first example is supposed to be YAML, and you are loading it and dumping YAML again. in YAML, you need a space after a colon to mark it as a key value pair. This is implemented differently in libraries, and some don't need the space. So you should always add the space.

Comment: HI @larsks & tinita thanks for response, my error got resolved, As larsks said dictionary format which i am using is incorrect, After changing my dictionary to correct format it working fine.